# How to execute mail Task process on camunda cockpit?

Tags: java, node.js, camunda, camunda-modeler

we have workflow that has service task attached to the box , Below template is applied to bmpn:serviceTask, Now when we deploy workflow to camunda using `https://engine-rest/deployment/create` , we are able to run the process but we see this error on incident tab,we are using `bpmn-js` node library for modeler and create workflows, where we define `camunda:class`, as you can see error below, Any idea how to resolve this camunda class issue ?

we are just trying to send email notification when process starts ?

New to camunda stuff any help will be appreciated.

template.js

```
{
  "name": "Mail_Task_2",
  "id": "com.camunda.example.MailTask_2",
  "createdBy": "sh529u",
  "users": [],
  "groups": [],
  "properties": [
    {
      "binding": {
        "name": "camunda:class",
        "type": "property"
      },
      "editable": false,
      "value": "com.mycompany.MailTaskImpl",
      "type": "String",
      "label": "Implementation Type"
    },
    {
      "label": "Sender",
      "type": "String",
      "binding": {
        "type": "camunda:inputParameter",
        "name": "sender"
      },
      "constraints": {
        "notEmpty": true
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "Receivers",
      "type": "String",
      "binding": {
        "type": "camunda:inputParameter",
        "name": "receivers"
      },
      "constraints": {
        "notEmpty": true
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "Template",
      "description": "By the way, you can use freemarker templates here",
      "value": "Hello ${firstName}!",
      "type": "Text",
      "binding": {
        "type": "camunda:inputParameter",
        "name": "messageBody",
        "scriptFormat": "freemarker"
      },
      "constraints": {
        "notEmpty": true
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "Result Status",
      "description": "The process variable to which to assign the send result to",
      "type": "String",
      "value": "mailSendResult",
      "binding": {
        "type": "camunda:outputParameter",
        "source": "${ resultStatus }"
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "Send Async?",
      "type": "Boolean",
      "value": true,
      "binding": {
        "type": "property",
        "name": "camunda:asyncBefore"
      }
    }
  ],
  "appliesTo": [
    "bpmn:ServiceTask"
  ]
}
```

ERROR

```
org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: ENGINE-09008 Exception while instantiating class 'com.mycompany.MailTaskImpl': ENGINE-09017 Cannot load class 'com.mycompany.MailTaskImpl': com.mycompany.MailTaskImpl
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.util.EngineUtilLogger.exceptionWhileInstantiatingClass(EngineUtilLogger.java:78)
```

Comment: Do you have a class `MailTaskImp` in the `com.mycompany` package ?

Comment: where i can find `com.mycompany` ? i am not a java guy i build modeler with node library and deploy diagram to camunda that is using java.

Comment: Where did you get your example? I think you forgot to copy the class with.